# Hive Index can't REBUILD - DAG failed du to vertex failure

Tags: hadoop, indexing, hive, hiveql, hortonworks-data-platform

I use Hive14 on HDP2.2 and have a problem with indexing on Hive. I can create an index.

```
create INDEX ix_key ON TABLE DbTest.Tbl_test(TEST_KEY)
as 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.index.compact.CompactIndexHandler' WITH DEFERRED REBUILD;
```

After that I load data into the table and built the index.

```
ALTER INDEX ix_key ON DbTest.Tbl_test REBUILD;
```

Hive built the index and it works fine, performance increased. Now I want to rebuild the index, but always get an error:

```
INFO  : Session is already open
INFO  : Tez session was closed. Reopening...
INFO  : Session re-established.
INFO  : 

ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1426585957958_2810_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1426585957958_2810_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: Tbl_test initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1426585957958_2810_1_00 [Map 1], java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.DynamicPartitionPruner.initialize(DynamicPartitionPruner.java:135)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.DynamicPartitionPruner.prune(DynamicPartitionPruner.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:109)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:245)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:239)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:239)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:226)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]
ERROR : Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1426585957958_2810_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_1426585957958_2810_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:null]
ERROR : DAG failed due to vertex failure. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask (state=08S01,code=2)
```

The base table exists, I can run queries against it. The index table exists too. If I create a new index on another table and run rebuild-command, I get the same error.
I tried it with beeline and CLI - the error is always the same.

Hope anyone has some ideas how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to fail in the dynamic partition pruner, which you can turn off with "hive.tez.dynamic.partition.pruning=false". You also might want to consider filing a bug here: https://issues.apache.org

Comment: Thanks for this reply, but it seems not to be the solution. Pruning was set to true, I changed it to false. Wanted to execute statement again, same failure.